# Select all items using a button in a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I would like to select and deselect all the items in the listview using "SelectAll" and "DeselectAll" buttons. I wrote the code for SelectAll but it throws a `NullPointException`. I couldn't find the bug in my code. Can someone point out the error in my code.

```
final ListView list;
String[] listItems = { "Enabled" };

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facilities)));
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);                                       

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)arg1;
        //other functionality!                                              
    }
});

OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int itemCount = getListView().getCount();
        System.out.print(itemCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
            list.setItemChecked(i, true);
            //getListView().setItemChecked(i, chk.isChecked());
        }
    }
};

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code...

```
private OnClickListener checkAllCheckboxes = new OnClickListener()
{
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
       ListView lv = getListView();
       int size = getListAdapter().getCount();
       if(lv.isItemChecked(0))
       {
           for(int i = 0; i<=size; i++)
           {
              lv.setItemChecked(i, false);
           }
       } 
    }
 }
};
```

Comment: I used the above code but still I face the same error. The application closes unexpectedly and does throw NullPointException.

Comment: Since getListAdapter() is used in your above code, Should my MainActivity extend ListActivity to have getListAdapter method? If I do so, I am getting "RunTimeException: Your content should have a ListView whose id is android.R.id.list"

Comment: in your xml file you have to use android:id="@android:id/list"

Answer (score 0):

You Can create One ArrayList of data class

```
class data
{
boolean chekced=false 
create setter and getter of this 

}
```

Create ArrayList of Data Class intially Chekced is false in all arraylist items 
When select is called set all items to true 
Then moify adpater and call notifyDatasetChanged on listView

This is how you can do this